# What is the difference between “/var/lib” and “/var/run?”

Tags: linux, unix, path

I am studying Unix-like filesystem structure especially [FHS (Filesystem Hierarchy Standard)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard). Anyways I know in the recent FHS `/var/run` is moved to `/run`.

I can’t understand the difference between lib and run. Can someone elaborate this with an example?

Answer (score 5):

See [this website for more details](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html). In short:

- [`/var/run`](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#VARRUNRUNTIMEVARIABLEDATA) (Run-time variable data) contains data that’s associated to running programs; in particular these files should be (re)created at boot/start.
- [`/var/lib`](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#VARLIBVARIABLESTATEINFORMATION) (Variable state information) on the other hand contains data that should persist between program invocations and over reboots.

Answer (score 0):

`/var/run` (or, more recently, `/run`) is for "[system information data describing the system since it was booted](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/ch03s15.html)". Such system information include PID files and named sockets. Examples:

- `sshd` PID file
- `dockerd` socket file
- `autofs` named pipes
- `rpcbind` lock files

Note that `/var/run` is for *system* information. For program-specific ephemeral data, `/tmp` or `/var/tmp` would be better suited.

---

`/var/lib` is for "[[holding] state information pertaining to an application or the system](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/ch05s08.html)". So this directory would be a good candidate for persistent application data. Examples:

- Docker stores containers, images, and volumes in `/var/lib/docker`
- NFS stores operational details in `/var/lib/nfs`
- Package managers like `dnf` and `apt` store state here between invocations.
- `logrotate` tracks its previous runs here.

Files in `/var/lib` should be internal to the program and are not meant for user interaction or manipulation.